# Solana smart contract event listener

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust, node

I have to implement an event listener for my solana smart contract, where if any user deposits any funds into the contract, I want to record that transaction in the db using event listeners. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Solana RPC exposes websocket endpoints where you can listen to transactions that invoke your program, using the `programSubscribe` endpoint.

More info at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/programsubscribe